# Retornar total de documentos de uma Coleção no MongoDB?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb

Fiz uma `api` em `C#` e é a primeira vez que uso o Mongo como banco e em uma rota preciso obter o total de registros que tenho na minha `Collection`.

Tentei de varias maneiras mas não consegui encontrar uma maneira de retornar um numero `int` e fazendo algumas pesquisas eu encontrei essa maneira mas ela me retorna um tipo long.

```
private async Task<long> CountVacancyAsync()
    => await _collection.Find(x => x.Activy.Equals(true) || x.Activy.Equals(false))
                        .CountDocumentsAsync();
```

Existe alguma forma mais correta de retornar o total de registros e precisa ser mesmo do tipo `long`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O Pacote `driver` criado para [MongoDB](http://MongoDB.Driver) só oferece um método para contar a quantidade de documentos de uma coleção com o tipo de retorno `long`, [foi assim escrito e assim que deve ser utilizado](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.10/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_IMongoCollection_1_CountDocumentsAsync.htm).

*Código:*

```
Task<long> CountDocumentsAsync(
    FilterDefinition<TDocument> filter,
    CountOptions options = null,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = null
)
```

Mas, talvez possa utilizar o método `AsQueryable()` da interface `IMongoQueryable<T>` (que é o [linq](/questions/tagged/linq) para [MongoDB](http://MongoDB.Driver)) e nesse caso possa ter o resultado para o tipo `int`, *exemplo*:

```
int count = _collection.AsQueryable().Count();
```

---

Outro problema no seu código é esse método `find` que é desnecessário nesse código, pode escrever de uma maneira mais resumida:

```
private async Task<long> CountVacancyAsync() => await _collection.CountDocumentsAsync();
```

***Nota:*** só escreva filtros quando for necessário, porque, o seu da pergunta se auto anula trazendo todos, então, não é necessário fazer um filtro.

Se quiser utilizar mesmo assim (que como já foi citado é desnecessário, mas, uma forma de exemplificar como poderia escrever) utilize assim

```
.find(new BsonDocument())
```

<sup>***Referencias:***</sup>

- [IMongoCollection.CountDocumentsAsync Method (FilterDefinition, CountOptions, CancellationToken)](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.10/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_IMongoCollection_1_CountDocumentsAsync.htm)
- [Site MongoDriver](http://MongoDB.Driver)
- [Package Nuget - MongoDB.Driver](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MongoDB.Driver)